# Start video capture activity in Google Glass

Tags: android, android-activity, google-glass

Basically I'm creating a small app which should record video when receiving a ping from another computer.

I have extended the Google Glass [stopwatch example](https://github.com/googleglass/gdk-stopwatch-sample/tree/master/src/com/google/android/glass/sample/stopwatch) in order to create a basic live card. I removed `ChronometerView.java` and changed `CountDownView.java` so it does not count down but opens a `ServerSocket` and displays text once it receives a ping from another computer.

This all goes well, but now I want to start Glass' [built-in camera activity](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/camera) from `CountDownView.java` once the signal is received. Simply inserting the below code does not work as (for as far as I understand) `CountDownView.java` does not extend `activity`.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_VIDEO_REQUEST);
```

So how do I start the camera activity at this point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to start the activity from a context. Follow the steps below to test it first:

In StopwatchService.java, add:

```
private static StopwatchService mAppService;     

public static StopwatchService appService() {
    return mAppService;
}   

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mAppService = this;
}
```

In CountDownView.java, at the end of `public CountDownView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int style) {...}`, add:

```
mHandler.postDelayed(mLaunchVideoRunnable, 1000);
```

Also in CountDownView.java, add:

```
private final Handler mHandler = new Handler();  
private final Runnable mLaunchVideoRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        StopwatchService.appService().startActivity(intent);
    }
};
```

Note that you need to add FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or your app would crash. After you test run this, you can copy the code to where you receive the socket data.